# MYSQL Move data from one table column to another table column if condition is matched

Tags: mysql, database, data-migration

i'm not really an mysql guy more like a php guy :)

I have an issue with copying values from one table column to another table column.

The trick is that the data should be copied only if condition is matched. So basically i want to transfer categoryID from one table to another if postIDs are the same.

i have two tables **news** and **news_in_category**

in **news** table i have the following columns (**id, title, categoryID**)

in **news_in_category** i have the following columns (newsId, newsCategoryId)

So i want to move newsCategoryId to categoryID if newsId is the same as id.

For example if news table id=99 it should look up in news_in_category table find the newsId with value 99 and copy the newsCategoryId value to news table categoryID with id 99

Hope it makes sense to you :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE news n
JOIN news_in_category nic ON n.id = nic.newsId
SET n.categoryID = nic.newsCategoryId
```

It looks like you might have a redundant functional dependency: `newsId -> categoryId`.  If so, you could drop the `news_in_category` table without any loss of information, after running the query above.